# how to change a Character to another Character

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, char, ascii

I Wanna Know how to change a Character that user type in an usual *Textbox* into another Character

for Example:

if user type "**A**" in the *Textbox* , I wanna the programme to type "**B**"

and if user type "**N**" in the *Textbox* ,  I wanna the programme to type "**M**"

and if user type "**Y**" in the *Textbox* , I wanna the programme to type "**S**"

And so..

so when user type "**ANY**" i need the text in the *textbox* to be "**BMS**"

ـــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ

i have solved the problem from [Custom TextBox Control that Switches Keyboard Language Automatically c# WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407823/custom-textbox-control-that-switches-keyboard-language-automatically-c-sharp-wpf/21408475?noredirect=1#comment32326686_21408475)

Comment: actually i am a kind of a beginner and i don't know what i should do to do that

Comment: Based on your other question, it looks like you want to make a language-specific TextBox, where for example typing a Q will insert a ض, typing a W will produce a ص, and so on. Isn't an Arabic IME better suited for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a dictionary that contains information about what to change with what like this

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"A", "B"},
    {"N", "M"},
    {"Y", "S"},            
};
```

You can simply do that by overriding the OnTextInput method in your own custom class. So your complete code for your own custom class will be

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"A", "B"},
            {"N", "M"},
            {"Y", "S"},            
        };

        protected override void OnTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            string str;
            if (myDict.TryGetValue(e.Text, out str))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                if (SelectionLength == 0)
                    Text = Text.Insert(CaretIndex, str)
                else
                {
                    SelectedText = str;
                    SelectionLength = 0;
                }

                CaretIndex += Text.Length;
            }

            base.OnTextInput(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution, but there are a few problems: `AppendText(str)` does not take the current CaretIndex into account, so that should be `Text = Text.Insert(CaretIndex, str)`. That also requires a different way to update the CaretIndex - setting Text apparently resets the CaretIndex to 0, so we need to store the original value before setting the Text property, and then replace `CaretIndex = Text.Length` with `CaretIndex = originalCaretIndex + str.Length`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the textbox's `OnTextChanged` / `TextChanged` event (which depends on whether you are doing win forms or .net).

You can access the current value of the text box using the textbox's `Text` value.

You will need to save the old value to compare against so you can keep track of which characters you have already changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, make a textbox and double click on it. Then a method shows up, and you insert the following code:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "ANY")
            textBox1.Text = "BMS";
    }
```

The method checks if your textbox contains the string "ANY" and changes it to "BMS". 
You can also alter this method so it changes the letters for every single letter you write. For instance:

```
A -> B
BN -> BM
BMY -> BMS
```

This will give the feeling that the word changes while it is being written instead of when the entire word has been written.

Comment: But i don't know the word that the user would write i put a simple example above..... i need to give every character that user can type on the keyboard another "valu" that add to the text box

Comment: But do you always want to change the text to "BMS"?

Comment: You can make more checks then, just add:
if (textBox1.Text == "something")
  textBox1.Text = "somethingElse";

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may solve your problem.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string finalValue;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {

            byte[] ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);

            List<byte> newB = new List<byte>();
            foreach (byte b in ascii)
            {
                byte s = b;
                s++;
                newB.Add(s);
            }

            finalValue = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newB.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why another list + call to ToArray() instead of modifying the ascii array?