# Custom TextBox Control that Switches Keyboard Language Automatically c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, char, ascii

i need to make something like that
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301832/Custom-Text-box-Control-that-Switch-keyboard-langu 
but for **WPF** and C#

i'v tried to do it with a simple **if** statement but i was have to put another textbox like that

```
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        if (textBox1.Text == "Q" || textBox1.Text == "q")
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text+ "ض";
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
        else if (textBox1.Text == "W" || textBox1.Text == "w")
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "ص";
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
        // and so ..
    }
```

it works but i want to do something like the link above

Comment: Doesn't that link provide you with the source code as well as an explanation as to what's going on and how it all works?  Seems the best approach would be to study the complete solution that you linked to, making edits where appropriate, and asking questions when you get stuck on a specific spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in WPF by creating a new custom Control that inherits TextBox. In that Create a new TextLanguage Property and Override the OnKeyDown method

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
    public enum TextLanguage
    {
        English,
        Arabic
    }

    public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {        
        public TextLanguage TextLanguage { get; set; }

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextLanguage != WpfApplication.TextLanguage.English)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
                {
                    // Shift key is down
                    switch (e.Key)
                    {
                        case Key.Q:
                            AddChars("ص");
                            break;
                        // Handle Other Cases too
                        default:
                            e.Handled = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None)
                {
                    switch (e.Key)
                    {
                        case Key.Q:
                            AddChars("ض");
                            break;
                        // Handle Other Cases too
                        default:
                            e.Handled = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }

        void AddChars(string str)
        {
            if (SelectedText.Length == 0)
                AppendText(str);
            else
                SelectedText = str;

            this.SelectionLength = 0;
            this.CaretIndex = Text.Length;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first i wanna thank you .... second i have some problems like that when user type in this text box and press "space" it do it with strange way "i need you to try it" and when user select some thing and type again the text that he select does not been deleted

Comment: @AhmedTarek I noticed it. It happens because we tell TextBox that we are going to manually handle all the key events. I've edited the code to correctly handle 'space' etc. Handle all the cases you want and in default set `e.Handled = false` so that TextBox can handle that.

Comment: thanks for your replay but code with this way gives me an error >> " Control cannot fall through from one case label ('default:') to another " ... actually even if i put `break;` after your edit it still not working ..  it always have the same problem that i told you about

Comment: Sorry I forget it's C# here we have to add `break;` after each case. I tested it. it's working fine now

Comment: the problem that i told you about is still there " the space key press & selected text still appearing after typing "

Comment: @AhmedTarek It's working fine. No such issue [Check this sample](http://zeetechteam.com/adnan/CustomTextBox.zip) and compare with your code.

Comment: Try type "Q" then press "space" and repeat this more than 2 times and you will find my first problem then select all "Q"s >> "ض" that you type then press "Q" one more time and you will understand what I am taking about --- P.S : i am very sorry for my a lot questions and comments but i really have to know this code

Comment: I have noticed it and updated the answer. Please check it now. Hope your problem solved